# Why text field is taking spaces as valid input in kendo UI forms?

Tags: regex, validation, kendo-ui

If I enter only spaces in a text field it is taking as a valid input in kendo forms. If I enter only spaces then it should return false and if I enter spaces along with text then it should return true.

Can anyone provide the regex pattern for this? I can easily pass this pattern in kendo fields and validate.

[Please check this link and test for first and second fields](http://dojo.telerik.com/UmIKa/4)

Comment: `^.*\S.*$` ..........

Comment: Hi Avinash, Thanks for your quick reply. I just used it in kendo form but its not working.  can please check with the above example link what I have provided.

Comment: still it is not working Avinash. you can try directly in my link  http://dojo.telerik.com/UmIKa/4